# I'm having issues with MonoDevelop, the code I copied is actually invisible except for the first letter on the whole code

Tags: unity-game-engine, monodevelop

I have some problems with monodevelop, I'm new at coding, just started this month, so I don't know much about these kind of programs.
My issue is that I copied a code from another script and it is there but it's invisible, it only shows the first letter of the whole script.

The first line of the new script (The "Invisible" one) just shows up like

[image: This]

But when I place the cursor at the right of the "U" and press the Supr. key, the next letter of the word shows up, like it was there the whole time but invisible. Like

[image: This]

The first line of the code was supposed to say "using UnityEngine;"

Comment: Stop using MonoDevelop, use [Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=Community&rel=15) instead.

Comment: Maybe its just a visual bug. Try to select everything again by either the mouse or CTRL+A and see if the lines get visible again

Comment: What's your platform and what version of monodevelop are you using?

Comment: +1 for @Draco18s, Monodevelop will soon be deprecated from Unity (starting from 2018), so it's better if you start to learn the ropes of IDEs directly with VS (which is better than Monodevelop, A LOT). ;)

Comment: It does not appear again if I press CTRL+A, but thanks for the reccomendation, will use VS from now on!